# Grass identification and removal

Tags: lawn-repair

Last year I used a patch fill seed mix from a big box store. This year those patches have taller and lighter colored grass than the surrounding lawn. In the picture below, these would the grass on the left.

[image]

1) What type of grass is this and how do I get rid of them?

2) I am planning to reseed my lawn with bluegrass seeds this season, am wondering if I should indeed get rid of these tall grasses before I reseed the lawn. Will the bluegrass smother out the tall variety.

Some close ups
[image]

[image]

[image]

Some more pics
[image]

[image]

Comment: 'Sedges have edges, grasses have knees and rushes are round'...I see sedges for the light colored grasses in the pictures.  Bluegrass would not be able to compete with these guys as new grasses.  I'd rake this lawn very well, get rid of the leaves and debris, pull these tall grass and mow!  No lower than 3".  Where is the label on this grass seed you used?  Was it for shade or wet soils?  Reseed with professional grass seed for your area, rake lightly, keep the seeded parts moist until mowable.  Is this in the shade?  If so forget growing grass.

Comment: I checked the labels on the seed packet. There is no mention of sedges, but has 70% Baverdi Annual Ryegrass seed along with fescue and bluegrass. I am familiar with bluegrass and fescue. So what is the likelihood that this is ryegrass?

Comment: @stormy That looks more like an answer than a comment.

Comment: I never know when to do one or the other properly, sorry!!  Grins.

Comment: Dinakar, annual ryegrass is very dark green.  Could you send a close up of this grass to include the crown?  Have you seen any seed from these grasses?  That would be definitive.  Did the label say 'zero weed seed'?

Comment: @stormy Yes, the label did say zero weed. No seed so far but it mowed regularly last season. I have added a few more pics to the main post. The stems are much thicker, more like a plant rather than a grass. I have KBG/Fescue surrounding this, dono if that makes a difference for the color contrast.

Comment: @stormy my research seems to indicate this nutsedge...what do you think?

Comment: Now I've a bit of doubt.  Could you pull up a chunk and try to take a picture of that connection of leaf to stem.  Cut one of those stems cross section, to see the structure and if it is hollow...if it is it would be a grass.  I'll have more questions when you've had time to do this.  Grasses, sedges and rushes are very tough to ID.  Look closely for any seed-making.

Comment: I mowed the lawn the other day...so will have to wait till they grow back. Turns out that the seed pack I used last year had a high percent of perennial and annual ryegrasses (70%) with fescues and bluegrass constituting the rest.

Comment: @stormy added two more pics....what do you think...sedge or ryegrass?

Comment: It looks kinda like zoysia to me. But I'm no expert.  I had grass that looked like this sprouting randomly in my lawn at my old house and my uncle (a lawn nut) told me it was zoysia. It was taller, lighter green than the rest, sort of like your first picture.

Comment: I am in Zone 5 and this grass was green through winter. I doubt it is Zoysia, which I understand will turn brown/dormant in the winter.